# How to post <p> data to controller action in Yii2.0

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, yii2

Here is my view

```
$student = Students_list::find()->orderBy('id')->all();

$editForm = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id'     => 'student-edit-form',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'method' => 'post'
]);

echo '<ol style="list-style-type: disc">';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($student); $i++) {
    echo '<li><p>' /* $student[$i]['id'] . ' ' . */ . $student[$i]['name'] . ' ' . $student[$i]['surname'] . ' ' . $student[$i]['age'] . '</p></li>';
}

echo '</ol>';

ActiveForm::end();
```

and i have a editAction in my controller. So I want to post `<p>` content to my controller by clicking and then edit it in my editAction.
please tell me how

Comment: what happens when you click the above view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view 'action' specifies the action to which the post value should go

```
 $editForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'     => 'student-edit-form',
        'action' => 'controller/action',
        'method' => 'post'
    ]);
```

so set the controller and view where you want your POST content to go.